# Is there an operator which calls error instead of next in Observables

Tags: rxjs

`of` operators emits `next` values.  Eg `of(1,2,3)` will emit values `1`,`2` and `3` by calling `next` of `of`. Is there an operator which can call `error`? I need this to simulate error handling in my unit test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not strictly necessary to use an operator for this.

Below an example where every forth value will be an error:

```
const observable$ = Observable.create(observer => {
    let n = 1;

    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        if (n < 4) {
            observer.next(n);
            n += 1;
        } else {
            observer.error("Error emitted");
        }
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
});

observable$.subscribe({
    next: x => console.log(x),
    error: x => console.error(x)
});
```

However if you are looking for an operator the `throwError` could be the one, which you are looking for. Details about it [can be found here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/throwError).